# Getting path of audio file from sdcard

Tags: file, audio, android-intent, path, record

In my app I tried to pass the file path from one activity to another activity using intent.In my receiving activity I got the file path as "null".But when I print the file in first activity it prints the path.From my second activity I attach that file to mail using Gmailsender.This was the code I tried,

```
   private void startRecord()
            { 
                  File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "test.pcm");

                  try
                  {
                        file.createNewFile();

                        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(outputStream);
                        DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(bufferedOutputStream);

                        int minBufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(8000,
                                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
                                    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

                        short[] audioData = new short[minBufferSize];

                        AudioRecord audioRecord = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
                                    8000,
                                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
                                    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                                    minBufferSize);

                        audioRecord.startRecording();

                        while(recording)
                        {
                              int numberOfShort = audioRecord.read(audioData, 0, minBufferSize);
                              for(int i = 0; i < numberOfShort; i++)
                              {
                                    dataOutputStream.writeShort(audioData[i]);
                              }
                        }
                        audioRecord.stop();
                        audioRecord.release();
                        dataOutputStream.close();

                  }
                  catch (IOException e)
                  {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                  }
                  String audiofile;
                  audiofile=file.getAbsolutePath();
                  System.out.println("File Path::::"+audiofile);
            }
```

Intent is,

```
  Intent sigout=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),WeeklyendActivity.class);
  sigout.putExtra("mnt/sdcard-test.pcm",audiofile);
  startActivity(sigout);
```

In my receiving activity,

```
   String patty=getIntent().getStringExtra("mnt/sdcard-text.pcm");

        System.out.println("paathhhy frfom ::"+patty);
```

It prints null.Can anyone help me how to get the file path.And more thing I am not sure whether the audio would save in that file correctly?

Please anyone help me!!!Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the extra you are adding (`audioFile`) really a `String`?

Comment: @David Wasser !!No its file

Answer (score 0):

Based on your information that `audioFile` is a variable of type `File`, when you do this:

```
sigout.putExtra("mnt/sdcard-test.pcm",audiofile);
```

you are putting a `File` object in the extras `Bundle`. Then, when you try to get the extra from the `Bundle` you do this:

```
String patty=getIntent().getStringExtra("mnt/sdcard-text.pcm");
```

However, the object in this extra is of type `File`, not type `String`. This is why you are getting `null`.

If you only want to pass the name of the file, then put the extra like this:

```
sigout.putExtra("mnt/sdcard-test.pcm",audiofile.getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: I will tell my requirement...I m implementing the audio recording in my application.Audio Recording works fine.I want to get the audio file which is used to record and pass it to next activity where it is going to be attached in mail...Now how can I pass file from one activity to another

Comment: You can just pass the filename to the next activity and open the file there. You don't want to pass a `File` object via `Intent` extras.